# converting image from grayscale to color pallete

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, colors

I am making a program where I have to convert a grayscale image to a color pallete image with different colors.

For instance, the grayscale picture would look like a black and white image while the final output should look like this:

[image: color pallete effect]

I figured out that I am supposed to use an if statement with the condition statenments(&& or ||). But I am having a hard time figuring out what to put into the if statements to create this effect. You can see in my program that i attempted to start it but that if statement i printed out did not do anything. If someone could help me with this then that would be great!

Thanks

My code:

```
import java.awt.*;
public class ConvertColor
{
    public static void main(String [] args) 
    {
        Picture pictureObj = new Picture("WashingtonMonument.png");     //creates a new Picture object representing the file in the parameter list                 
        pictureObj.explore();                                           //explore the Picture object which is currently the unaltered original image
        int redValue = 0; int greenValue = 0; int blueValue = 0;  int luminance = 0;      //declare and initialize the variables that hold the red, green, and blue values (0-255)

        Pixel pixelSource1 = new Pixel(pictureObj, 0,0);
        Color pixelColor = null;

        for(int y=0; y< pictureObj.getHeight(); y++)
        {
            for(int x=0; x< pictureObj.getWidth(); x++)
            {
                pixelSource1 = pictureObj.getPixel(x,y);
                pixelColor = pixelSource1.getColor();
                redValue = pixelColor.getRed();
                blueValue = pixelColor.getBlue();
                greenValue = pixelColor.getGreen();
                luminance = (int)((redValue * .5));

                pixelSource1.setColor(new Color(luminance, luminance, luminance));
            }
        }

        if(redValue > 50 && blueValue < 190)
            greenValue = (int) .5 * (pixelColor.getGreen());


        pictureObj.write("grayWashingtonMonument.png");
        pictureObj.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show some attempt? Your question looks like could you do this for me?

Comment: And also the original  assignment text? I don't see why insisting explicitly on using "if" and "&& or ||" should make any sense ...

Comment: What is it that you want to do in your if statement?

Comment: the if statement will produce the colors from the grayscale image @bhspencer

Comment: How do you get the colors for the new color palette? Are those just random? The line `pixelSource1.setColor(new Color(luminance, luminance, luminance));` is setting the pixel to a grayscale value. Maybe you can add a line before that with your condition. `if (redValue<128)` ...

Comment: What is your current output?

Comment: @Bryn did my answer helped yoj?

Answer (score 0):

To convert a gray to color using the value from brighter to darker, here is a solution using a switch/case statement :

```
     for(int x=0; x< pictureObj.getWidth(); x++)
        {
            pixelSource1 = pictureObj.getPixel(x,y);
            pixelColor = pixelSource1.getColor();
            redValue = pixelColor.getRed();
            blueValue = pixelColor.getBlue();
            greenValue = pixelColor.getGreen();
            int nr = 0;
            int ng = 0;
            int nb = 0;
            int tempResult = redValue / 21;

            switch (tempResult){
            case 1 : nr = 255; nb = 127;break;
            case 2 : nr = 255; nb = 255;break;
            case 3 : nr = 127; nb = 255;break;
            case 4 : nb = 255; break;
            case 5 : ng = 128; nb = 255;break;
            case 6 : ng = 255; nb = 255;break;
            case 7 : ng = 255; nb = 128;break;
            case 8 : ng = 255; break;
            case 9 : nr = 128; ng = 255;break;
            case 10 : nr = 255; ng = 255;break;
            case 11 : nr = 255; ng = 128;break;
            case 12 : nr = 255;break;
            default : nr = 255; ng = 255; nb = 255; break;}

            pixelSource1.setColor(new Color(nr, ng, nb));
        }
```

For 13 shades of gray, we have a corresponding color.

Answer to tell me if it worked well because I cannot test it myself. But the logic is correct.